# Laravel get data based on foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have 2 tables, TABLE1 and TABLE2.
They are linked throug Eloquent:
*TABLE1 **has many** TABLE2's, and TABLE2 **has one** TABLE 1.*
They are linked with foreign keys as such:
*in TABLE2 table1_id -> links to -> TABLE1 id.*

How do I retrieve **the entire table data or TABLE 2,** + replace *table1_id* with a column of table1 (let's say by booktitle for example)?

Sorry for the abstraction, but this is the best way I can explain it? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make use of Eloquent's eager loading and fetch all records from **table2** and their corresponding record in **table1**.

This will do the trick:

```
$results = Table2::with('table1')->get();

foreach ($results as $table2record) {
  echo $table2record->id; //access table2 data
  echo $table2record->table1->booktitle; //access table1 data
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the relationship in the models , for example if you have a "Category" and this has many "Products" you need to put this code in your model

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'foreign_key_you_have');
    }
```

and when you need to retrieve all products associated to that category in your view you need to call the function of model, for example

```
@foreach($category->products as $cp) // with $category->products you call all products associated to your foreign_key
  <h1>{{$cp->price}}</h1>
@endforeach
```