# Multiple Foreign Key from the same table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel application with a MySQL database that has 3 tables: `Publication`, `Comment` and `User`.

When I display a publication to user I call `WS GET Publication By Id` and `WP GET Comment By Publication Id` to display all comments related to that publication.

I want to know if there's a way to avoid Calling `WP GET User By Comment Id` for each Comment, because when I display a comment I also need to display some information for user who commented.

Can I add multiple user Foreign Keys in table `Comment` and use them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I don't understand what does the foreign keys have to do with the rest of the question...

Comment: Found the solution for my question in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047679/laravel-get-data-based-on-foreign-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic usecase. Can you see if this answers your question.

```
Publication model{
whatever fields you have,
//Comments --> One to many relation with Comment model
 public function comments()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
 } 
}

Comment Model{
whatever fields you have,
//User --> One to one relation with User model
 public function user()
 {
     return $this->hasOne('App\User');
 }
}

User Model{
fields...
}
```

In your controller, you can get the publications with comments and users by using with function.

```
$pub = Publication::first()->with('comments.user');
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Santhosh Thanks for your help ! But it's not the problem, what i want i call only Web Service for publication and Web Service for getting comments just one time, and to display user information under comment dont have to call User Web Service related to comment for each comment, hope it's more clear ? Thanks

Comment: We are talking about the same thing. You need to define relationship in thr model and use load or with function in controller to get the related fields. I see from the comment that you got the same solution.

Comment: Yeah i didn't understood your solution before, thanks, i will mrk it as the accepted response !